# Combining amphetamine and MAOIs

Tags: drugs, medicinal-chemistry

Could combining amphetamine and a (possibly selective) MAOI (MonoAmine Oxidase Inhibitor) increase the amphetamines potency without serious toxic side effects? If so by what factor, and would this be profitable for clandestine amphetamine producers to lower production costs?

I guess this is most at home at the Chemistry Stackexchange. I'm looking into this matter from a medicinal chemist point of view.